# Where can I find an example of a C# Workflow System?

Tags: c#

I am switching from C to C# after 15 years of doing C. I have been learning .NET on the side but my first .net job will be updating a workflow system (that's all I know). I would like to get a head start. Any pointers. I haven;t seen WWF mentioned so they might not be using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps: [Code Samples on Windows Workflow Foundation (WF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/wf-code-samples.aspx)
 Also if you know russian you can see some articles [**here**](http://nesteruk.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/on-visual-programming/) and videos [**here**](http://techdays.ru).
 Good Luck

Comment: Thanks. My knowledge of Russian is limited to pree-vyet, Borsh and kak dilla.

Comment: Still, there are video presentations, maybe they will be enough even without sound..also you can use this: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/net/46409/ (introduction to WF, but in russian again). BTW! You can use Google translate to translate the whole article page. It will become at least readable.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, I want to apologize for my english.

Studiyng MS Workflow Foundation to have an head start on a workflow system project is like buy an h**A**mmer to be able to drive an h**U**mmer. It is a nonsense given that MSWF is only a tool that helps you build workflow oriented projects. The probability is that the system does not use MSWFF at all(and there are good reasons to that).

Start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow) and then build up your knowledge by addressing the specs of the project, if you have any. Basically on that wiki page there's all you have to know on wf theory. Implementation will sure vary from project to project.

We're building a WF system too (and, surprisingly, we do not use MS WF Foundation) and i can tell you that all you need to build a great WF system is to start by focusing on the specific class of problems that the system will address. It's really really difficult, if not impossible, to build an all generic system.